# How can I check a team's match history?

Tags: league-of-legends

As the title states, is there any way of checking the history of a team, rather than an individual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you visit an individual's profile page, there are tabs at the very top. These tabs will display the individual's Summoner Name as well as the names of any teams they are on.

[image]

Select any team to view their Roster and Statistics. You can also see their history via the history button in the top menu. It will look something like this:

[image]

If you'd like the see the match history of another team, you can search for them in the box to the upper right (outlined in the above image in green). You can use either the team name (e.g. "Counter Logic Gaming") or their team tag (e.g. "CLG").